# Django modelforms externally-provided field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have created a modelform with five fields.

A user submits a POST form with four of those fields. How would I externally supply the additional field. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
def create_profile(request):
    variable = variable
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, additional_field=variable)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
```

How would I include this `addition_field` the the request.POST data to send to the database?

Comment: `form = ProfileForm(request.POST)`
`form.additional_field = variable`
`if form.is_valid():`
`form.save()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_profile(request):
    variable = variable
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.variable = variable
            profile.save()
            return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
instance = form.save(commit=False) 
instance.attribute = variable 
instance.save()
```